# Flask + Flask-Security + Babel not working

Tags: python, flask, flask-security, python-babel, flask-babel

I have setup with Flask + Babel + Flask Security.
Created all translation like this:

- root

  - main.py
  - translations

    - ru

      - LC_MESSAGES

        - messages.mo
        - messages.po

In main.py there is part to setup language which executes:

```
@babel.localeselector
def get_locale():
    user = getattr(g, 'user', None)
    if user is not None:
        print("User locale {}".format(user.locale))
        return user.locale
    # I put here constant to test
    return 'ru'
```

But http://localhost/login stayed untranslated. Can you please advice where else to dig? No errors in logs even with **Debug = True**

Comment: I found that translation applies for templates in *templates/* but not for *templates/security/*

Answer (score 2):

I have found that **Flask-Security** doesn't work with Babel out of box!
[This Pull Request fixes it partially](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security/pull/520) from WTF processing perspective.
To be able to translate Jinja2 templates as well following need to be amended in **core.py**

```
def render_template(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # Provide i18n support even if flask-babel is not installed
    # or enabled.
    kwargs['gettext'] = gettext
    kwargs['ngettext'] = ngettext
    kwargs['_'] = _
    return render_template(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, with me simply changing my imports to

```
from flask_babelex import Babel, gettext, lazy_gettext
```

made it all work fine with Flask-Security.

Answer (score 1):

You should tell to your app that your use a particular locale. I did that as follows:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_security import Security, SQLAlchemyUserDatastore
from .models import User, Role, 
from flask_babel import Babel

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User, Role)
security = Security(app, user_datastore)

babel = Babel(app, 'ru')
```